# Word Online (Business) Connector - Populate a Microsoft Word template - how to add new parameter dynamically?

Tags: azure-logic-apps, connector

Word Online (Business) Connector - Populate a Microsoft Word template - how to add new parameter dynamically?

I wanted to find a solution to add the parameter dynamically at the run time. right now you can define it at design time.

[image]

Comment: What value you want to set ? Please provide more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to add parameters at run-time. But, you can use Azure Logic App Expressions to define the value for a parameter at run-time.

Ref blog: https://www.serverless360.com/blog/azure-logic-app-expressions

Hope, it helps.